"I'll get do something" or "I'll get doing something"
Today, I learned an expresion from ELSA app. "What's the wifi password? I'll get set up now.", which confused me. As I know, It should be "I'll get doing something", e.g. "I'll get going now.". Is the expression "I'll get set up now." grammatically correct? If not, what other more natural expressions should I use?

There are some, but not many verbs that are often used in an "I'll get [verb]ing" pattern. "Get going" is quite common, as is "get cooking" or some others, but "I'll get setting up," while it would be reasonable and understood, wouldn't happen as often. For one thing, a phrasal verb like that with extra words would be less likely.

"Set up" can function as:

a verb phrase, as in "I will set up".
an adjective phrase, as in "I am set up".
a noun phrase (often hyphenated), as in "that's a nice set-up"

In "I'll get set up now", it is an adjective phrase, describing the state you are trying to achieve, just as if you said "I'll get finished now". If you wanted to use it as a verb, you could say "I'll start setting up now", or simply "I'll set up now".

Yes. Get dressed, get washed, get drunk, get dismissed from my job (etc).

Great explanation, it helps.

I will offer this answer to complement Astralbee's answer, which focuses on the grammar.
Usually to get set up involves the configuration of something.  The roadies of a rock band might need to "get set up" before the concert, making sure all the amplifiers and electronic instruments are connected.
Someone who administers polygraphs, for example, when told that they must administer one shortly, might say "I'll get set up now".  The meaning would be "I'll make the equipment ready and will prepare to administer the test".
In the original example, perhaps those words are spoken by someone who intends to participate in a group video game that requires specific equipment, something like a virtual reality headset, or perhaps to participate in a presentation before an audience, and they need to set up some audio-visual equipment or some sort of group conferencing software.
You want things to be set up, and so you have to get set up.
